# Finding Marriage Certificate/License most likely in 1930s Michigan?

Tags: united-states, marriage-records, 1930s, michigan

My grandparents were apparently married but I cannot find any proof.

They lived in Michigan and I've requested marriage information from more than 9 counties and it's getting expensive!  My mom was an only child, her parents never celebrated their anniversary and upon my grandparents death, there was no marriage certificate in their belongings.  My mother was born in 1937.

Can you please direct me where to obtain the date and location, or the certificate itself?

My grandfather died in 1965, my grandmother in 1976.  I assume she drew Social Security off my grandfathers SSN as he retired from Aeroquip of Jackson, Mi.

My grandmother  born in 1899, was the youngest of 9,  ALL her siblings marriage information was easily found.  She was married once before, that husband died in 1931.

I'm at a loss, I've been searching for this information for 14 years!

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! Where were your grandparents residing between 1931 & 1937? If you can't pinpoint them those years, where are they in the bracketing census years? Have you looked for the marriage in the online marriage databases for Indiana? -- a popular marriage destination for Michiganers and others whose states had stricter marriage requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!  Between 1931-1937 my grandfather was in Jackson, Mi and Grandma was is Flint, then turning up in Jackson in the 1940 census, married with an almost 3 year old (my mom).   I will check Indiana databases as I have already done for Illinois.

Answer (score 1):

The [Seeking Michigan site](http://seekingmichigan.org/) is a great resource that I've used for finding my ancestors' death certificates, census records, marriage records, etc.

I have not looked for your ancestors there but you might like to.